# Accessing a decorated class

Tags: python, class, decorator

I have inherited a project. I am not too good with decorators, but I am learning!

I have 2 classes, both of which are decorated. They are in separate files. I would like to call a class method from class2 in a method in class1. Something like this:

```
@class_decorator
class Class2(object):

    @classmethod
    def generator(cls):
    for s in my_stuff:
        yield s

@class_decorator
class Class1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = [1,2,3]

    def some_funct(self):
        for a,b in zip(self.my_list, Class2.generator()):
            print "{} {}".format(a,b)
```

I get an AttributeError, NoneType has no attribute generator

Is this because Class2 is decorated? Am I not able to call a classmethod on Class2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@class_decorator
class Class2(object):
```

is (except for a technical caveat) exactly equivalent to

```
class Class2(object):
    ...
Class2 = class_decorator(Class2)
```

(The technical caveat is that if Class2 modifies class_decorator, then the two
could be different.)

---

The error message

```
AttributeError, NoneType has no attribute generator
```

suggests that when Python reaches `Class2.generator()`, `Class2` is `None`, and therefore Python can not find its `generator` attribute.

Now you might wonder, how could `Class2` be `None`? It could happen if `class_decorator` returns `None`, since that would cause `Class2` to become equal to `None`:

```
Class2 = class_decorator(Class2)
```

So check that `class_decorator` returns a class:

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    # modify cls
    return cls      # The error could be due to this line being missing
```

Comment: Good call, that's most likely the source of the problem. But I thought this was working code???

Comment: Wait, how could `Class2` survive the same faulty decorator and be instantiated? The distilled code is not showing what's really going on.

Comment: @alexis: You are right -- it's hard to say exactly what is wrong without runnable code and a full traceback error message.

Comment: @unbuntu, thank you, the class decorator was missing the return statement. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It must be something the decorator does. Normally a decorator should *not* be getting in the way of this-- unless it's intentional. I extended your code with a trivial decorator (and a value for `my_list`), and it runs fine:

```
def class_decorator(cls):
    return cls
```

So track down `class_decorator` and see what it does.

Comment: thank you, the decorator was not returning a class. So, None was returned.